# Scala Generics with case class extending sealed trait

Tags: scala

The following code will not compile, and I don't understand the reasons why not

```
class FruitProcessor[T <: Fruit] {
  def process(fruit: T) = {
    // Do something with fruit
  }
}

class FruitBlender[T <: Fruit] {
  val fruitProcessor = new FruitProcessor[T]

  def blend(fruit: T) = {
    fruit match {
      case b: Banana => fruitProcessor.process(b)
      case a: Apple => fruitProcessor.process(a)
    }
  }
}


sealed trait Fruit
case class Banana(id: String) extends Fruit
case class Apple(id: String) extends Fruit
```

The compilation error is along the lines of "found Banana, required T"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Drop the `T`, and replace it with `Fruit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `process` method requires an argument of type `T`, but you pass it a value of type `Banana`. The compiler isn't smart enough to figure out that `T` is always `Banana` in the code path where `fruitProcessor.process(b)` is called. Actually you don't need that match expression at all. In this case the `T` in the method `blend` is the same as the `T` that `process` wants. So you can just call `fruitProcessor.process(fruit)`.

Answer (score 1):

To spell out what you do: 
You have a `FruitProcessor` parameterized with a subclass `T` of `Fruit`, which can `process` `T`s.
You then make a `FoodBlender` also parameterized with a subclass `T` of `Fruit`, which has a `FoodProcessor[T]`, i.e. it can `process` all kinds of `T`.

Since you can only `process` `T` and not `[S <: Fruit]`, i.e. only the specific instances of your subtype of `Fruit` `T`, which the blender is parameterized with, and not all `Fruit`s, this cannot work with the specific types `Banana` and `Apples`. The `T` on the `FruitBlender` could for example be `class Pear extends Fruit`, and in that case the signature of `blend` would be `def blend(fruit: Pear)`, which of course if not compatible with `Apple`s or `Banana`s.